# Play 2.3 Webjars - default requirejs support - How to write define or require

Tags: requirejs, playframework-2.3, webjars

I am trying to get requirejs and webjars working, but they do not seem to work in play 2.3.7

routes:

```
GET      /vassets/*file     controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file)
GET      /webjars/*file     controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

build.sbt

```
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
    "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.3"
```

html template

```
<script>
    @Html(org.webjars.RequireJS.getSetupJavaScript(routes.WebJarAssets.at("").url))
</script>
<script data-main="@routes.Assets.versioned("js/koapp/js_init")"
  src="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("require.min.js"))"></script>
</head>
```

js_init.js (require.js data-main)

```
function test(){
  return console.log('test');
}
require("jquery",test);
```

I am getting the error **"Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"**

Also, I tried using define inside the main js. It is not able to locate the dependencies then, it is looking for libs in the same folder as main js.

```
   define([ 'knockout'],
        function(ko) {
  console.log('hello world')       
});
```

is requirejs + webjars integration completely broken or am i doing something nonsense? please help

Comment: What line of what file is throwing that error?

Comment: js_init.js, the data-main of requirejs. The code that I have in this file is just a function, followed by a require call as shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WebJars Play2 Activator Template](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/webjars-sample-play2) has all of this stuff working in it.  So you should compare what you have with what is in there.

I think that `data-main="@routes.Assets.versioned("js/koapp/js_init")"` needs to include the `.js` extension, like: `data-main="@routes.Assets.versioned("js/koapp/js_init.js")"`.

Also, the `/vassets` route should be:

```
GET        /vassets/*file    controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Notice the `Asset` type on the `file` param.

Comment: Hi, now if i call the require inside the main js file. it works however define does not work. Calling define throws the error in require.min.js, says "Uncaught Error: Script error for: knockout". I have updated the code that I have used for define in the question

Comment: I guess i need to override the requirejs config right? is it possible to just add my custom modules to the generated config?

Comment: Check out [the WebJar docs](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) for info on how to override the RequireJS config.

Comment: Thanks. Sent you a PR in github to include webjars-requirejs for knockout